# Rails - Generating email attachments that work in Apple Mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, email-attachments

I have a Rails app that sends a PDF to the user.  I am producing this email with the following mailer code:

```
  def new_file_notification
    mail(:to => 'test@test.com', :subject => "File for #{Time.now.to_s(:uk)}") do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        attachments['my_file.pdf'] = File.read(Rails.root.join('tmp', 'my_files', "my_file_#{@my_file.id}.pdf"))
      end
    end
  end
```

Whilst this produces an email that is fine in Sparrow and the GMail interface, this does not come out well in Apple Mail.  I see the attachment, but do not see any of the email HTML, but also have a second blank attachment called "Mail Attachment.pdf"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should remove `format.pdf` as doesn't this suggest that PDF is a viable format for the e-mail itself? It should only be .html or .text I think. Your attachment should just go under HTML format.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly it.  Thanks